# Umbraco: Save and Publish as administrator is adding two audit trail logs

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

In Umbraco7, when I just save and publish any document as an administrator, I can see two logs created in the audit trail for one save and publish event.

I have found that it is known issue that Save and Publish gives 2 logs from below links, but **the problem is I am getting 2 logs with 2 different user names. One is my username while the other one is the super admin** I created while first time launching Umbraco.

http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-636#tab=Linked%20Issues

http://our.umbraco.org/forum/core/general/11325-audit-trail-2-publishes

Any help is appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Was this issue solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you no user is specified on the [Save method on the ContentService](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/Management-v6/Services/ContentService), then the superadmin is used.

Probably you are using [ApplicationEventHandler](http://our.umbraco.org/Documentation/Reference/Events/application-startup) to handle an "after publish".  Or some packages is using these events.  Having multiple events might result in multiple logs.

Comment: Updating user id and making save with out raising events is doing the job. Thanks Dampee, it helped.